# NHibernate persist order for adding object to collection

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm probably making a newbie mistake here, but I can't figure out how to make this work. I have two entities - `Parent` and `Child`, where one `Parent` can have many `Child`ren. The problem seems to be that when I add a new child to a parent, the parent can't cascade save the child, because the child instance doesn't have an ID yet. On the other hand, the child can't be persisted on its own, so it has no way of getting an ID...

My mappings:

```
public ParentMap()
{ 
    // ID and other properties

    HasMany(p => p.Children).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad();
}

public ChildMap()
{
    // ID and other properties

    References(c => c.Parent);
}
```

Now, I might already have a parent record in my database, and I want to add a child to its collection of children. To do so, I create a new instance of the `Child` class, add the child to the parent's `Children` property (of type `IList<Child>`). I also fetch the parent record and sets the childs `Parent` property to the parent entity.

When I try to save this, I get errors no matter which order I try to do it.

With `Save(p)`, saving the parent record and hoping the child will be saved on cascade, I get the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ChildID', table 'dbo.Children'; column does not allow null values. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

If I try the other way around, i.e. first saving the child, then adding it to the parent and saving the parent, I get the following error:

> null id in Application.Domain.Entities.Child entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

In what order should I call `parent.Children.Add(child)`, `child.Parent = parent`, `session.Save(parent)`, and `session.Save(child)` to make this work? Is something missing in my mapping configuration?

**Update:** I've added `.Inverse()`, and tried the following without success:

```
// First of the above errors
session.Save(child);
child.Parent = parent;
parent.Children.Add(child);
session.Save(parent);

// Second of the above errors
child.Parent = parent;
parent.Children.Add(child);
session.Save(child);
session.Save(parent);

// Second of the above errors
child.Parent = parent;
parent.Children.Add(child);
session.Save(parent);

// Second of the above errors
child.Parent = parent;
parent.Children.Add(child);
session.Save(child);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't with NHibernate at all, but rather with my database configuration - I had forgotten to configure the ID column of the `Children` table. As soon as I specified the ID column, everything worked as expected: no `.Inverse()` needed, and I could save just the `Parent` and the `Child` is saved on cascade.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your relation as `Inverse` on parent's side. This will say NHibernate that child's side manages the relation:

```
HasMany(p => p.Children).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad().Inverse();
```

This forces you to set `child.Parent = parent` manually, but you're doing it anyway, so I believe it's not a problem.

By default, NHibernate assumes that it's parent's responsibility to set a foreign key on a child. And the logical order of operations look somehow like this:

1. Parent is to be saved
2. Children are saved due the cascade - we have no Parent ID yet (at least we could not have, I don't know why it works like that when we know it, too)
3. Children are INSERTed with `null` in Parent's foreign key
4. Parent is then successfully INSERTed, its ID is fetched
5. Children have Parent's foreign key UPDATEd.

In your first scenario, it fails at no 3 as you have not nullable foreign key column and NHibernate is not smart enough to find any solution.

Setting `Inverse()` tells Parent to not care about Child foreign key and it's your responsibility to set `child.Parent` properly. On save in this case, there are only INSERTs, as expected and no tries to set `null` in foreign key.

Comment: With `.Inverse()` as you suggested, I still get exactly the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `Cascade.All()` with `References`. We shouldn't put `Inverse()` on `HasMany`:

```
public ParentMap()
{ 
    // ID and other properties

    HasMany(p => p.Children).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad();
}

public ChildMap()
{
    // ID and other properties

    References(c => c.Parent).Cascade.All();
}
```